# Grails Update Dependencies : Error Compilation error: startup failed | Compile error during compilation with javac

Tags: grails, workspace

I am trying to run a grails 2.1.1 web app. While checking out the project from the SVN repo, it tries to do an update dependencies and fails with the following error:

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sm026588/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails/grails-plugin-log4j/jars/grails-plugin-log4j-2.1.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sm026588/.grails/ivy-cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Compiling 45 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
error: error reading /Users/../.grails/ivy-cache/com....intent/intent-processing-protobuf/jars/intent-processing-protobuf-2.10.2.jar; cannot read zip file entry
1 error
1 error
```

I have tried deleting the jar and re-run "refresh dependencies", did not work. Tried to see if the jar file could be unzipped, and I could unzip it successfully, which tells me that the jar is not corrupt. Tried with Eclipse Juno, STS and Eclipse Indigo on Mac OS X, all of them give the same error. Have been stuck at this point for quite sometime, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try completely removing your Ivy cache

Comment: that did not help. I blew up the whole ivy-cache, still the exact same error.

Comment: If your project is a multi module Maven project, try to remove the parent from the Grails project POM. I have had same kind of problems with the build failing at the point where Grails tries to compile plugins if the project is a child of a multi-module project.

This happens on Maven 3 and Grails 2.2.0